# Home Screen Takes a Long Time to Display After Removing Phone From Dock

Tags: motorola-droid, launcher, docking-station

When I remove my Motorola Droid from my docking station, my home screen is blank for a long time. It sometimes takes over 10 seconds for my app icons to display, and even longer for widgets to display. Is there any way to eliminate this pause? Am I doing something wrong?

**NOTE:** I am using the LauncherPro app as a launcher/home screen app, but I get the same behavior with the default Android launcher app.

Comment: I get the same thing with my Droid X. Even after the home screen comes up and I can use other apps, it takes a few minutes (sometimes up to ten) for the system clock to update.

Comment: I also see this behavior.  It sometimes happens on screen unlock as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've read, the reason this happens is because of the Android memory management, which I read was made "worse" because of a better internal task killer in 2.2 Froyo. The app is being marked as not needed in memory anymore and is being killed.

There are a couple things you could do to mitigate the frequency of this happening. There's an app on the market called [MinFreeManager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.dustypixels.minfreemanager) which modifies some system config files to change how the memory manager divides up memory to active apps. Get the app and load the preset `Aggressive`. Hit both `Apply` and `Apply at boot`. Also, you need to be ROOTED to do this.

Another thing I've seen suggested is in the LauncherPro settings, go to `General Settings` and check the box for `Keep in memory`.

Since doing both of these things, I have seen a reduction in homescreen redraws.