# What is causing music playback to stop/pause unexpectedly?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, music, music-player, motorola-droid

Moto DROID v1
Android 2.2.1

Is anyone else experiencing random music playback stopping/pausing on their handset?  Do you know what is causing it, or how to prevent it?

I've been trying to get to the root of the issue, and I think it has to do with the music playback service.  I've tried several apps (stock Music app, DoubleTwist, Cubed (3)).  In each case the behavior is the same.  Seemingly at random, and with now obvious trigger, music playback will pause/stop.  I've seen this both with and without bluetooth, wifi, Last.FM scrobbling, and headphones.  It does not correlate to notifications, as I get e-mail, text, and other notifications and playback continues.  My music files are stored on the MicroSD card.  Could this be due to latency in loading a portion of a file?

Comment: Moto DROID v1 Android 2.2.1 I too have been experiencing this since the Froyo update. I thought it may have something to do if the accelerometer detected a bump as it usually happend in my car or out for a walk. Pandora however has also been randomly pausing when just sitting on my desk.

Comment: Update: I'm still getting this behavior.  I tried Winamp.  I tried deleting all of my music with iTunes DRM.  Still pausing though. Just happened with the default music app playing a track at the 1:49 of 2:37 mark of a Beck track.  Music app was in the foreground, phone is in the multimedia dock, and I'm using wired headphones.  The music arrow is no longer in the system tray, but the app is shown.  The 1:49 indicator is blinking.  When I press play, the music continues.

Comment: I have a milestone 2 with this issue. Does it more on bluetooth speakers and headset, less in car with cable. Sometimes play icon is there sometimes not. Removed ticks to download lyrics and info, still happens. Happens on different songs and different memory cards. Was even worse when song's were in separate folders I.e. by artist/ album etc, this caused phone to freeze and had to take battery out. Now mp3 are in 1 folder just get this stopping issue. Have 2000 mp3. Checked all songs with two different mp3 checkers. All tags ok I think. Use card reader to transfer onto blank card phone format

Comment: I.m running into the same behaviour with the stock music player on a Dell Streak running 2.2 from OTA update. Phone came loaded with 1.6. Have performed factory reset with no luck. Happens when using either built in speaker or plugin headphones. Has anyone pinned anything down on this?

Comment: Just tried the new version of the Music app with cloud beta.  It still mysteriously pauses -_-

WinAmp app seems to be free of this defect.

Comment: My HTC Desire running Cyanogenmod 7 also does this. It just randomly pauses every now and again. Unpausing it causes it to carry on as it was without a problem, but it is still annoying!

Comment: I've found what causes it. i think its a "feature". If i turn my phone when NOT locked, to be horizontal, my music pauses. no headphones in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have resolved the issue by resetting my phone to factory defaults.  After resetting to factory default, I am no longer experiencing the mysterious pauses when playing music.

My rev. 1 Moto DROID came loaded with Android 2.1.  I ran the OTA update to 2.2, and then the OTA update to 2.2.1.  In addition to the music playback issue, I was also experiencing [extreme delays when displaying the launcher after the phone had been in a dock](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123/home-screen-takes-a-long-time-to-display-after-removing-phone-from-dock). I hadn't performed a factory reset since loading the two OTA updates, so I went through the factory reset process.  The home screen now displays much, much more quickly when removing the phone from a dock, and I have not experienced the music pause issue.

Comment: I was hoping this wouldn't be the solution :)

Comment: Maybe that resolved because the reset "cleaned" your unused apps that were consuming memory?

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually in the music app when it happens or is it when it is running in the background and you are doing something else?

If it's the latter, it is most likely because your phone is running out of memory and is killing the music player's service.

Go to Settings --> Applications --> Running Services and see if there are any running services that you can remove that would free up some memory.

To confirm if it is a memory problem, run a logger app right after the app gets killed and see if there are out of memory messages being logged or garbage collection going on.

Comment: It happens regardless of whether the app is in the foreground or background, I have seen it happen in both scenarios. The app screen shows thay the song is just paused at some random point. I checked memory usage and I have plenty of room to spare. It is a really irritating bug.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bad music file. One that has errors in it. Does it happen to specific files?

Otherwise it can be that Android is running out of memory. This is evident when the play arrow icon at the top left corner disappears when the music stops.

Comment: I have seen both scenarios (music arrow disappears, music arrow persists).  The music file currently being played is fine, as hitting the play button again to unpause the song will continue playing the rest of the song.  I recently cleared out all of my music files that had iTunes DRM to see if that might be causing it.  Will see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different headsets, if that's what your using?

it sounds like your headset is signalling pause/resume, you mention it happens on BT as well so I'm wondering if its something to do with the headphone jack socket, either dirt in the socket or a wiring fail inside...

Comment: Yes, I've tried different headsets (a Rocketfish bluetooth headset and skull candy wired headphones).  The behavior occurred with both headsets.